# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report! - July 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, monthly

## Welcome Our SharePoint Stack Exchange Valued Contributors.

We would like to share with you the **Most Active Contributors Report** over the last month!

[image]

**This report includes the following awards:**

1. Monthly Leader Board.
2. Most Active Contributors Award.
3. Most Active Editors Award.
4. Most Active Voters Award.
5. Most Close Votes Review Award.
6. Most First Post Review Award.
7. Most Late Answer Review Award.
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.
9. Most Reopen Review Award.
10. Most Suggested Edit Review Award.
11. Highest Votes Questions Award.
12. Highest Votes Answers Award.
13. Most Viewed Questions Award.
14. 1st Top Contributors summary list.

---

[image]

[image]

You can find the full list at [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/month/sharepoint/2017-07-02)

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                   REPUTATION
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                   2318
2   Aakash Morya               1167
3   Gautam Sheth               1014
4   Trevor Seward              835
5   moe                        799
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                    EDITS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                   239
2   Aakash Morya               99
3   Robert Lindgren            45
4   moe                        27
5   Mike                       20
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     VOTES
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Aashirya                   752
2   M.Qassas                   314
3   Aakash Morya               284
4   DVG                        275
5   Littel.Eden                227
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     41
2   Aakash Morya                 29
3   Asad Refai                   27
4   moe                          24
5   Gautam Sheth                 19
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Aakash Morya                 85
2   hoffie4                      72
3   Gaurravs                     62
4   M.Qassas                     43
5   Robert Lindgren              30
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Aakash Morya                 21
2   Gaurravs                     20
3   hoffie4                      15
4   Gautam Sheth                 13
5   M.Qassas                     11
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                     58
2   Aakash Morya                 43
3   M.Qassas                     37
4   moe                          29
5   Robert Lindgren              22
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Aakash Morya                 14
2   M.Qassas                     13
3   moe                          8
4   Asad Refai                   5
5   Robert Lindgren              4
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Aakash Morya                 59
2   moe                          32
3   Gaurravs                     28
4   M.Qassas                     17
5   Robert Lindgren              13
```

---

[image]

1. [How to check whether the current user has edit permission for a particular list using JSOM in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219852/how-to-check-whether-the-current-user-has-edit-permission-for-a-particular-list)

   - **Quest Owner:** Jeeva Jeyapaul.
   - **Votes:** 10.
2. [Sharepoint App Secret Expiration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220860/sharepoint-app-secret-expiration)

   - **Quest Owner:** Chad.
   - **Votes:** 7.
3. [Restrict SharePoint default pages from using custom master page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220070/restrict-sharepoint-default-pages-from-using-custom-master-page)

   - **Quest Owner:** user729271.
   - **Votes:** 7.

---

[image]

1. [Web Application and Site Collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220875/web-application-and-site-collection/220877#220877)

   - **Answer Owner:** M.Qassas.
   - **Votes:** 10.
2. [How to check whether the current user has edit permission for a particular list using JSOM in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219852/how-to-check-whether-the-current-user-has-edit-permission-for-a-particular-list)

   - **Answer Owner:** Gautam Sheth.
   - **Votes:** 10.
3. [Prevent special characters in list item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219833/prevent-special-characters-in-list-item/219835#219835)

   - **Answer Owner:** Juan Pablo Pussacq Laborde.
   - **Votes:** 8.

---

[image]

1. [How to check whether the current user has edit permission for a particular list using JSOM in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219852/how-to-check-whether-the-current-user-has-edit-permission-for-a-particular-list)

   - **Views:** 667.
2. [Problem with StringBuilder C#](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220408/problem-with-stringbuilder-c)

   - **Views:** 467.
3. [How to add this People Picker in Sharepoint form?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220916/how-to-add-this-people-picker-in-sharepoint-form)

   - **Views:** 258.

---

[image]

1. **Most Active Contributors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
2. **Most Active Editors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
3. **Most Active Voters Award.**

   - [Aashirya](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/62708/aashirya) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
4. **Most Close Votes Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
5. **Most First Post Review Award.**

   - [Aakash Morya](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/52649/aakash-morya) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
6. **Most Late Answer Review Award.**

   - [Aakash Morya](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/52649/aakash-morya) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
7. **Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
8. **Most Reopen Review Award.**

   - [Aakash Morya](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/52649/aakash-morya) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
9. **Most Suggested Edit Review Award.**

   - [Aakash Morya](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/52649/aakash-morya) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
10. **Highest Votes Questions Award.**

    - [Jeeva Jeyapaul](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/61067/jeeva-jeyapaul) Great Question, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
11. **Highest Votes Answers Award.**

    - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Answer, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
12. **Most Viewed Questions Award.**

    - [How to check whether the current user has edit permission for a particular list using JSOM in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219852/how-to-check-whether-the-current-user-has-edit-permission-for-a-particular-list)

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering, We fully appreciate all the great contributions of SE members. Please keep your valuable contributing!

> **P.S.:** This report will be published Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback & precious suggestion!

Comment: great. Thank you for your efforts and time.

Comment: Many congratulations to all.. Glad to be ranked in every pattern.. Thanks @M.Qassas for your efforts..

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP Thanks, bro, happy to see your precious comment :)

Comment: @AakashMorya Congratulation my bro, you really deserve that and thank you for valuable contributions :)  Keep it up ;)

Comment: Congratulations to all.

Comment: Congratulations Everyone. Keep the good work.